# What exactly is this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following set:

$\{X \in P(\mathbb{N}): |\complement{X}|< \infty)\}$

All subsets $X$ of $\mathbb{N}$ whose complement $\complement{}X$ is a finite set.

Is my interpretation in words correct?

Is it correct that the only infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ itself?

Therefore the set above includes all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ except for the set whose complement is $\mathbb{N}$. Is $P(\mathbb{N})$ the universe and would the empty set then be the set whose complement is $\mathbb{N}$?

$\{X \in P(\mathbb{N}): |\complement{X}|< \infty)\} = \{X \in P(\mathbb{N}):X \neq \emptyset  \}$

Comment: $\{1,3,5,..\}$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my interpretation in words correct?

Yes, the interpretation is correct.

> Is it correct that the only infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathbb{N}$ itself?

Most certainly not. For example, the set $\{2,3,4,5,\dots\}$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$.

In fact, for a given subset $X\subseteq \mathbb N$, you have three options. You could have that:

1. $X$ is infinite, and $X^c$ is finite (for example, $X=\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ is infinite, and $X^c=\{1\}$ is finite) or
2. $X$ is finite, and $X^c$ is infinite (for example, $X=\{1\}$ is finite, and $X^c=\{2,3,4,\dots\}$ is finite) or
3. $X$ is infinite, and $X^c$ is infinite (for example, $X=\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, \dots\}$ is infinite, and $X^c=\{1,3,5,7,\dots\}$ is infinite).

The only option that is impossible is to have $X$ finite and $X^c$ also finite (as this would mean that $\mathbb N=X\cup X^c$ is also finite).

Comment: So there are infinitely many infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ whose complements are finite and thus the set in question is also infinite?

Comment: @LinusDieLinse If by "the set in question", you mean "$\{X \in P(\mathbb{N}): |\complement{X}|< \infty)\}$", then yes, this set is infinite. For example, it contains **at least** the sets $\{1\}^c,\{2\}^c,\{2\}^c,\dots $.